# Unable to send g-mail after hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, sendmail

This is my code to send email after registration is successful. It works fine on my localhost IIS server. But after deploying web-site on server email is not sent to user. There is no exception or error message shown.

```
MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("xyz@gmail.com", TextBoxEmail.Text.Trim());
mm.Subject = "Password Recovery";
mm.Body = string.Format("Hi ,<br /><br />Your password is .<br /><br />Thank You.");
mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new NetworkCredential();
NetworkCred.UserName = "xyz@gmail.com";
NetworkCred.Password = "xyz";
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
smtp.Port = 587;
smtp.Send(mm);
message = "Registration successful. Activation email has been sent.";
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + message + "');", true);
```

same code work on password recovery page. but here it is not working.

I did some changes in code and also create a new page for registration now it is showing a following error

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

first i thought that it is error of mail sending code but it work fine on iis local server and also on other page. so i think may be it is a problem of button click event. just able to reach here.  please some help me as i know i get my answer here.

my new code:

```
   using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
                {
                    mail.From = new MailAddress("xyz@gmail.com");
                    mail.Subject = "mailSubject";
                    mail.Body = "mailBody";
                    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

                    mail.To.Add("xyz@gmail.com");



                    using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587))//2nd parameter is PORT No.
                    {
                        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("xyz@gmail.com", "xyz");
                        smtp.EnableSsl = true;//set this as your Host Name properties, for gmail,its true
                        smtp.Send(mail);//actual sending operation here
                    }
                }
```

Comment: try 465  as outgoing port.

Comment: Often providers require that Host used is their own host. I had same issue with one provider until they told me that I have to set their Host.

Comment: I thought so...but same code is working on another page for password recovery

Comment: please some one help me,  I spend two days on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to use `System.Net.Mail`, not the deprecated `System.Web.Mail`.

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

var fromAddress = new MailAddress("from@gmail.com", "From Name");
var toAddress = new MailAddress("to@example.com", "To Name");
const string fromPassword = "fromPassword";
const string subject = "Subject";
const string body = "Body";

var smtp = new SmtpClient
{
    Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
    Port = 587,
    EnableSsl = true,
    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
};
using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
{
    Subject = subject,
    Body = body
})
{
    smtp.Send(message);
}
```

Also, You have to create a specific Google password for that app via:

`Google> Account> Security> Apps> Manage apps> Add an app`
Select a name `My Awesome App` and Google will generate a custom password.

Another advice is Allow Less Secure Applications in your google account: [link](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps)

And finally, take in mind that Google don't allow you to send more than 250 messages per hour, no more than 1000 per day (not sure of the last number).

Comment: i tried this one but not working. my code is working on another page but don't know what problem on this page

Comment: @kish try a new app password.